# Test a single DAG that makes a network roundtrip

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have a task that reads a list of files from Azure and pushes the results to an XCOM. The operator is specifically the `AzureDataLakeStorageListOperator`. The source is here: [adls_list_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/adls_list_operator.py)

I want to print the output of this task using something like a `BashOperator` but I am unsure how to do this locally. As far as I can tell, the `airflow test` command only does single tasks, and so I can't get the output of my first task in testing my second task.

Here is my full DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.adls_list_operator import AzureDataLakeStorageListOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['vishaalkal@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('adls', default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = AzureDataLakeStorageListOperator(
    task_id='list_adls_files',
    path='reportdata/*.csv',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    bash_command='date; echo "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull("t1") }}"',
    dag=dag
)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

I believe I've set up authentication correctly as it was giving me `AccessDenied` errors before but no longer raises an exception.